# Add test case with robot.api

Tags: python, robotframework

How to add a test to a `robot` file from the `API`?

I tried this (see code below) but it does not work.

Does anyone have an example of adding test cases on a robot test via the `API`? I'm probably not using the `API` features correctly.

```py
from robot.api.parsing import *
from robot.api import TestSuite
from RobotFrameworkTests.Tests.CONSTANTS import *

class TestModifier(ModelTransformer):

    def visit_File(self, node):
        # print(node.sections)
        for test_case_sections in node.sections:
            if type(test_case_sections) == TestCaseSection:
                print("test_case_sections.body : " + str(test_case_sections.body))
                
                new_test = [KeywordCall([Token(Token.SEPARATOR, '    '), Token(Token.KEYWORD, 'Log'), Token(Token.SEPARATOR, '    '), Token(Token.ARGUMENT, 'Third Example'), Token(Token.EOL, '\n')])
                    ,KeywordCall([Token(Token.SEPARATOR, '    '), Token(Token.KEYWORD, 'Keyworddddd1'), Token(Token.SEPARATOR, '    '), Token(Token.ARGUMENT, 'Yooo'), Token(Token.EOL, '\n')]),
                    EmptyLine([Token(Token.EOL)])]

                test_case_sections.body.append(new_test)

                print("Test cases : ")
                for test_case in test_case_sections.body:
                    print("    " + str(type(test_case.body)) + str(test_case.body))


        # Call `generic_visit` to visit also child nodes.
        return self.generic_visit(node)


model = get_model(CURRENT_TEST_NAME, curdir=CURRENT_PATH)
TestModifier().visit(model)
model.save(CURRENT_PATH+'//modified.robot')
```

Robot Test :

```
*** Test Cases ***
First Example
    Log    First Example
    Keyword1    Regaeman

Second example
    Log    Second Example

*** Keywords ***
Keyword1
    [Arguments]    ${arg}
    Log    Keyword1 ${arg}

Keyword2
    [Arguments]    ${arg}
    Log    Keyword2 ${arg}
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION :

```
class TestModifier(ModelTransformer):

    def visit_File(self, node):
        for test_case_sections in node.sections:
            # Find TestCaseSection
            if type(test_case_sections) == TestCaseSection:
                # Create TestCase
                new_test = TestCase(
                    header=TestCaseName([Token(Token.TESTCASE_NAME, "test3"), Token(Token.EOL)]),
                    body=[KeywordCall([Token(Token.SEPARATOR, '    '), Token(Token.KEYWORD, 'Log'), Token(Token.SEPARATOR, '    '), Token(Token.ARGUMENT, 'Third Example'), Token(Token.EOL)])
                     ,KeywordCall([Token(Token.SEPARATOR, '    '), Token(Token.KEYWORD, 'Keyworddddd1'), Token(Token.SEPARATOR, '    '), Token(Token.ARGUMENT, 'Yooo'), Token(Token.EOL)]),
                     EmptyLine([Token(Token.EOL)])]
                )
                # Append TestCase to current node
                test_case_sections.body.append(new_test)

                print("Print test cases for debug : ")
                for test_case in test_case_sections.body:
                     print("    " + str(type(test_case.body)) + str(test_case.body))

        return self.generic_visit(node)
```

Comment: Now you can accept your own answer - so called self-answering..

Comment: to make it more valuable for future readers, please explain the changes compared to the code in the question.

Comment: @iLuvLogix basically yes, but not immediately. For self answered questions there's a longer ([48 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)) waiting time before OP can accept.

Comment: @jps True, slipped my mind ;)